# FB Graph Subscription IOS send access_token

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There is something to the Facebook Graph SDK (and its iOS implementation) that really makes my life miserable. And it seems I'm on my own, because I don't seem to be able to find anyone on the 'net with a similar problem/lack of understanding like me.

Without further ado:

I have this code in my iOS app, that is supposed to subscribe my app to user updates:

```
-(void)subscribeToFacebook{
    (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) ? NSLog(@"is open") : NSLog(@"is closed");

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"page", @"object",
                            @"http://www.example.com/fbcallback.php", @"callback_url",
                            @"about, picture", @"fields",
                            @"ItsMeAlright", @"verify_token",
                            nil
                            ];
    /* make the API call */
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/app/subscriptions"
                                 parameters:params
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                              /* handle the result */
                               NSLog(@"error= %@",error);
                          }];
    }
```

When I run this code, an error is logged, stating:

> "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token."

Now, I (think) I know how to get the access_token

```
 NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];
```

but I have't got a clue on where and when to send it to Facebook.

I tried to append it to the @"/app/subscriptions" part like this

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString
                           stringWithFormat:@"/app/subscriptions?access_token=%@",
                           [fbAccessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

but that didn't work.

Your input is extremely welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this will be to create a FBSession with the application token. Because the current session isn't what you want.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios#sessions

But, security wise, you shouldn't be doing this at all. It's very insecure to embed your application token in a production application. I believe that the iOS sample generated for you is incorrect.

You should be sending any request that requires the application token with a server call (e.g. PHP)

Comment: Hmm, I guess I just don't understand what this is all about. Should it be just a one time operation? That would make sense. In that case, should I run something like this http://marcneuwirth.com/blog/2011/12/08/facebook-real-time-updates/ and I will be in business?

Comment: @Sjakelien yes when you do the `POST` request to subscribe it will be a on time operation, unless you need to add more fields to subscribe to that is. Yes that blog looks like it should work on first glance.